# SQL Server slow query Entityframework

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, indexing

I have a large database with a table with over 200k records and it's getting slower on select from `PostQuery`. I am using Entityframework 6.0 with MS SQL Server 2014

**Structure:**

```
PostId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
PostQuery NVARCHAR(100)
PostData NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

**My Code:**

```
public PostViewModel GetPost(string post_query)
{
    var mb = db.Posts.Where(p => p.PostQuery == post_query).SingleOrDefault();
    if (mb == null) return null;
    return new PostViewModel
    {
        PostId = mb.PostId,
        PostData = mb.PostData
    };
}
```

my URL is like http://example.com/post/post_query/ (Over 150k URLs are indexed by Google so I can't change the URL structure)

I am still new to the large databases. What should I do?

Please help me speed up my site. Thanks

**UPDATE1:**

As Dai suggested I ran query using "Show Actual Execution Plan"

Query:

```
SELECT         PostId, PostData
FROM            Post
WHERE (PostQuery = 'example-query')
```

Result Test1:
[image: test2 result]

**UPDATE2:**

As DavidG suggested I turned on indexing as `CREATE INDEX IX_Posts_PostQuery ON Posts (PostQuery)` and ran the above query again in management studio.

Result Test 2:
[image: test2 result]

Is there anymore things needed to be done?

Comment: Get the query that EF is running, then run it in SQL Server Management Studio with the "Show Actual Execution Plan" feature enabled. After the query completes it will show you what the query bottlenecks are and if you need any new indexes.

Comment: As you're using `PostQuery == post_query` my guess is that your `PostQuery` column is not indexed.

Comment: Side-note: you can simplify your Linq query to just `this.db.Posts.SingleOrDefault( p => p.PostQuery == post_query )` - there is no need for a separate `.Where` application.

Comment: @Dai: Yes Sir, it's not. I don't know much about indexing but I am gonna do what you have suggested. I am at very early stage of databases and websites. Thanks so much for your valuable time.

Comment: are you referring to `Is Full-text Indexed`?

Comment: You may just need a simple index, something like this: `CREATE INDEX IX_Posts_PostQuery ON Posts (PostQuery)`. But @Dai is correct, you really need to get a query plan to figure it out.

Comment: @ArbazAbid No, a Full-Text Index is something different - it's meant for more advanced text searching (it indexes each individual human-readable natural-language word). It has a large overhead and requires special SQL Server services and would be overkill for this case. You just need a simple index (See @DavidG's `CREATE INDEX` command) which is all you need for equality `==` matches.

Comment: @Dai Yes Sir, I got it. working on that. Thanks so much for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: @ArbazAbid What is the definition of `PK_Post` and what was the query you tested? Please update your original question rather than putting them in a comment.

Comment: @Dai I have updated my Question Sir. Please take a look. Is there anything else I should do? Performance increased significantly.

Comment: @ArbazAbid There's another optimization you can make by including the `PostId` in the index (using the `INCLUDE` clause) but that might be overkill.

Comment: @Dai: how to do that sir, can you please give me an example. Thanks

Comment: @ArbazAbid I recommend reading this and other articles on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx

Comment: @Dai I have a question, should I use in memory OLTP tables? Please let me know what you think about this. Thanks

Comment: @ArbazAbid With respect, your original posting suggests you're not familiar with many key database concepts, so diving into OLTP would likely confuse you further.

Comment: @Dai you are right sir, I am reading about Databases all day long these days. Thanks so much for your time.